# Android: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5

Tags: android, string, file

I get the exception from the title when I run my app. What it does is it has a .txt file with words for a Hangman game and I think the exception is thrown when accessing the file. My file, cuvinte.txt is located into /assets/. Here is my code (i skipped the layout/xml part, which works fine):

```
public void onCreate() {
    // all the onCreate() stuff, then this:
    try {
        AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("cuvinte.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String rand;
        while((rand=b.readLine())!=null){
            cuvinte.add(rand);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No words file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    newGame(newG);
}

public void newGame(View view){
    Random rand = new Random();
    String stringCuvant = cuvinte.get(rand.nextInt(cuvinte.size()));
    cuvant.setText("");
    System.out.println(stringCuvant);
    for(int i = 0; i< stringCuvant.length(); i++){
        cuvant.append("_ ");
    }
    incercari.setText(valIncercari);
}
```

The function newGame() is called both when the new game button is pressed and at the beginning of the activity, in the onCreate() function.

Comment: you should close those readers after you're done with them

Comment: For the sake of professionalism, please name your variables in English :)

Comment: In my case, I experienced this because I was trying to pass an int parameter inside a `setText()` function.

Answer (score 616, accepted):

(Just assumption, less info of Exception stacktrace)

I think,  this line, `incercari.setText(valIncercari);` throws Exception 
because `valIncercari` is `int`

So it should be,

```
incercari.setText(valIncercari+"");
```

Or

```
incercari.setText(Integer.toString(valIncercari));
```

Comment: or even better: `Integer.toString(valIncercari);`

Comment: From above code there is no any other code line which cause this exception. Only the line which I pointed in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have come across this type of problem, but every time it showed a syntax error for the incompatibility of types (String required vs int given). That is why I never even took into account that may be the problem.

Comment: same as String.valueOf(); which does call Integer.toString and other respective toString methods

Comment: I am wondering why Android Studio does not advice you. I had the same problem setting an int value into TextView.setText for error.

Comment: @bheatcoker - because `setText(int)` also used to get string resource by id. And In Android all resource id has `int` value.

Comment: Was struggling for the same since two days. Cleaned, rebuilt invalidated cache and what not. Bdw this should be handled automatically.. Not expected.

Comment: String.format is the recommended way. setText(String.format(
                        Locale.US,
                        "%d",
                        valIncercari
                ));

Comment: Correct answer. I was trying to textview.settext(integer). Now I have replace my code with textview.settext(String.valueOf(integer)); and its works. Thanks.

Comment: Still year is 2020 and Android Studio does not warn against this.

Answer (score 20):

Another scenario that can cause this exception is with DataBinding,
that is when you use something like this in your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="point.to.your.model"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@{model.someIntegerVariable}"/>

</layout>
```

Notice that the variable I'm using is an Integer and I'm assigning it to the text field of the TextView. Since the TextView already has a method with signature of `setText(int)` it will use this method instead of using the `setText(String)` and cast the value. Thus the TextView thinks of your input number as a resource value which obviously is not valid.

Solution is to cast your int value to string like this

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(model.someIntegerVariable)}"
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also after that you need to `Build` -> `Clean Project` in Android Studio to re-generate Data Binding classes.

Answer (score 19):

Just wanted to point out another reason this error can be thrown is if you defined a string resource for one translation of your app but did not provide a default string resource.

### **Example of the Issue:**

As you can see below, I had a string resource for a Spanish string "get_started". It can still be referenced in code, but if the phone is not in Spanish it will have no resource to load and crash when calling `getString()`.

**values-es/strings.xml**

```
<string name="get_started">SIGUIENTE</string>
```

**Reference to resource**

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.get_started)
```

**Logcat:**

```
06-11 11:46:37.835    7007-7007/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.test PID: 7007
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0700fd
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
        at com.juvomobileinc.tigousa.ui.signin.SignInFragment$4.onClick(SignInFragment.java:188)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

### Solution to the Issue

Preventing this is quite simple, just make sure that you always have a default string resource in `values/strings.xml` so that if the phone is in another language it will always have a resource to fall back to.

**values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="get_started">Get Started</string>
```

**values-en/strings.xml**

```
<string name="get_started">Get Started</string>
```

**values-es/strings.xml**

```
<string name="get_started">Siguiente</string>
```

**values-de/strings.xml**

```
<string name="get_started">Ioslegen</string>
```

Comment: This one hit when I copied resources from one Android Studio project to another and I copied the strings.xml file. Due to some caching/reloading/whatever it discarded the new file and kept the old one. So I had the string ids from the translation but not from the plain string.xml

Answer (score 12):

This problem mostly occurs due to the error in `setText()` method

Solution is simple put your `Integer` value by converting into `string` type
as

```
textview.setText(Integer.toString(integer_value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime this happened due to not fond any source like if i want to set a text into a textview from adapter then i should use

```
 textView.setText(""+name);
```

If you write something like

```
 textView.setText(name);
```

this will not work and sometime we don't find the resource from the string.xml file then this type of error occur.

Answer (score 0):

Using DataBinding and setting background to the `EditText` with resources from the drawable folder causes the exception.

```xml
<EditText
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:text="@={viewModel.model.name}"
    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_roman" />
```

**Solution**

I just change the background from   `android:background="@drawable/rectangle"` to  `android:background="@null"`

Clean and Rebuild the Project.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a numeric value to a text field. You have to convert the numeric value to a string with:

```
String.valueOf(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we add resources in dimen or any other recourse folder, we forget to add dp.

```
<dimen name="exercise_value">4</dimen>
```

For example, I was facing this issue because I forgot to add dp in my value.
Then I changed it into

```
<dimen name="exercise_value">4dp</dimen> <br>
```

Boom. Error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve it I had to replace:

```
Toast.makeText(this, my_int_var, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(my_int_var), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```