# XML wont display stored SQLite data

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have some XML which should be displaying the hour from TimePicker data but every time I try to view the data it force closes. I've narrowed the issue down to an incorrect setup in my XML file(s) but I can't seem to correct the issue and keep the app from force closing.

view_country xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/nameText" 
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>

<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/capText"
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>

<TableRow>       
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>                    
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/codeText"
style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>
<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="Linked Users"/>         
<TextView 

style="@style/StyleText"/>         
</TableRow>
<TableRow>         
<TextView 
style="@style/StyleLabel"
android:text="Time Limit"/>         
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>  


ViewCountry java 



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 
   private TextView timeTv; 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
         int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         timeTv.setText(result.getInt(timeIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
   }
}



Database Connector




import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   } 

   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
   }       

   public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("cap", cap);
              newCon.put("time", time);
              newCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code,  String time) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name", name);
              editCon.put("cap", cap);
              editCon.put("time", time);
              editCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }


           public Cursor getAllContacts() 
           {
              return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                 null, null, null, null, "name");
           }

           public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
           {
              return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
           }

           public void deleteContact(long id) 
           {
              open(); 
              database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
}
```

AddEditCountry java

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private TimePicker timeEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
      timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);


      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));  
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(),
            timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
            codeEt.getText().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

add_country xml (where TimePicker data which is causing the crash is first entered into the system)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:padding="5dp">

  <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/name_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

  <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
     android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
     android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Data Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10MB" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Unlimited Data" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="10kbs" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="1"
    android:hint="@string/code_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




  <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(UPDATED) LOGCAT:

```
03-22 06:14:34.855: D/Activity(4860): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 06:14:34.915: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4860): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 06:14:34.915: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d4c3000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:60
03-22 06:14:34.965: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d8f7000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:64
03-22 06:14:34.985: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-22 06:14:34.985: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dc05000 size:614400
03-22 06:14:34.985: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dc9b000 size:614400
03-22 06:14:35.035: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:56
03-22 06:14:37.748: D/Activity(4860): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 06:14:37.828: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4860): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 06:14:37.828: D/memalloc(4860): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e131000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:59
03-22 06:14:37.828: W/ResourceType(4860): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
03-22 06:14:37.828: W/dalvikvm(4860): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410889d8)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3622)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(ViewCountry.java:74)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.ViewCountry$LoadContacts.onPostExecute(ViewCountry.java:1)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-22 06:14:37.838: E/AndroidRuntime(4860):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI element `"@+id/timeEdit"` defined in layout `view_country.xml` is a TextView. You are tring to cast it to `android.widget.TimePicker` in your activity `ViewCountry`.

There is another UI element with same id ("@+id/timeEdit") which indeed **IS** TimePicker but it's placed in layout for `AddEditCountry` activity.

Check your `ViewCountry` layout and code, probably element `@+id/timeEdit` shouldn't be a TextView, or you should cast it to TextView in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're understanding what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to display a ListPicker in AddEditCountry.java then save the ListPicker currentHour with AddEditCountry.java then come over to ViewCountry.java and view the currentHour, minute etc : ) 


I know I almost have the two activites connected - but something is causing them to fail (and I'm pretty sure it's XML related - but I just cant get the two activites to communicate)

Comment: Basically I'm trying to connect the TimePicker UI element ("@+id/timeEdit") in AddEditCountry.java / add_country.xml

to 

 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  


in view_country.xml / ViewCountry.java where it will display the time the user saved via the TimePicker I already have in add_country

Comment: I undersand your intentions, I've just suggested that in your ViewCountry activity you are performing "lookup" of view_country.xml's timeEdit and casting it to WRONG widget type. Cast it to TextView instead of TimePicker: (line 38) timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);  (as a side result this line: timeTv.setCurrentHour(result.getInt(timeIndex)); will stop to compile, you'll have to replace it with comething from TextView's API.

Comment: Awesome - I changed timeTv = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit); 

to 

timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);

cleaned the project, but now I'm getting a new error stating  "Type Mismatch cannot convert from TextView to TimePicker" on line 38

Comment: You have to change type of timeTv reference: from TimePicer to TextView (line 22 if I counted correctly). Next, replace every timeTv.setCurrentHour with timeTv.setText (in ViewCountry activity only)

Comment: (continued) replece timeTv.getCurrentHour() with timeTv.getText() as well. When you'll store timeTv.getText() in Intent's extras, you may want to convert String to Integer, it depends on how you'll be using this information.

Comment: I updated all references as requested (and posted updated src from View Country above as well as an updated LOGCAT - it's still crashing)

Comment: Somewhere in you DB related code you are storing "time", and in other place you are retrieving it, pay attention if you use same types for storing and retrieving. Probably Integer is (mis)used as String (or vice versa). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11189583/2085106) answer will help you.

Comment: Should I update the references to TimePicker in AddEditCountry as well? (I still can't view the stored data - force close issues remain)

P.S.

Can I provide you with an updated logcat or something to try to pinpoint this? (I've been shooting in the dark on this issue all day and everything I've tried  thus far hasn't allowed me to view the data without a force close error)

Comment: Don't update reference types in AddEditCountry. AddEditCountry has to have TimePicker, ViewCountry has to have TextView (both having same id is harmless coincidence). What's important: Timepicker gives you time as an Integer, and TextView content is a String. You have to store time as String or Integer, it's your decision, but once made you have to respect it and use proper method while retrieving it. Learn how to safely convert  Integer to String and vice versa, you'll need it. Then adapt your code to your data model. Here's a snippet for you: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kXiX6jyE)