# Can't start another "Activity" in Android - Gives Error

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, resources

This is simplified version of a larger code. I've just started with Android programming and badly stuck with this problem for past an hour.

```
    /**Main Activity**/

    sumBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SumActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("var1", et1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("var2", et2.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This code takes two variable from the text boxes and drives the user to another activity where the sum of these numbers will be shown.

Here's the Target Activity:

```
    public class SumActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sum);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("var1"));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("var2"));
    int c = a+b;
    tv.setText(c);
}
```

There are associated xml files inside res/layout folder for all the classes I've created.

**Sample from my Manifest.xml File**

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.summer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.summer.SumActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.summer.DifActivity"></activity>
```

**LogCat**
[image]

Comment: In the LogCat view, highlight the lines of the exception, and press `<Ctrl>-<C>` to copy them to the clipboard. You can then paste them as text into your question. This is much better than screenshots, as you can capture the entire stack trace, not just what fits in a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting int to TextView in `tv.setText(c)` method, so textview thinks you are passing id of string (like R.string.name etc.). You need to do this:

```
tv.setText(c + "");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem

```
 tv.setText(c);
```

change it to

```
 tv.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```

There are different `setText()` methods as you will see [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29). The one that you are calling, which accepts an `int` as a parameter, is used to find a resource with that 'id' so you need to change your variable to a `String`. This is why you get a `Resource Not found` exception. It can't find a `String resource` with the `id` of whatever variable `c` is.

Just a side note but you might want to wrap your parsing code in a `try/catch` unless you are doing some other error checking or you may end up with a `Number Format Exception` if the user enters a non-integer value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int a = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("var1"));
int b = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("var2"));
int c = a+b;
tv.setText(c);
```

The setText() overload that you are calling expects either a string or an integer representing a resource identifier. Since the type of `c` is `int` it is interpreting it as a resource identifier!

Replacing the last line with this should fix it:

```
tv.setText(Integer.toString(c));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, and ussualy look at your logcat. It's seems the first strings are reported by a problem - "android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception string resource id". That really means setText() method should contain a string parameter. The same issue related to a solution of your problem [Android: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189545/android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x)