# Learning to debug

Tags: java, android, debugging, logcat

Good morning,

I am learning to debug applications and have create a test application which returns an "Unfortunately, LearningActivities has stopped." message when I press my button in the app.

The app is pretty basic... Essentially, you type your text into n EditText field, and press the button and it should launch a second activity which displays that text in a TextView field.  As soon as I press the button is when I am receiving the error.

I have run a logcat on it and am looking for a little help in understanding what exactly I am looking at.

```
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917): Process: com.rcd.learningactivities, PID: 23917
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rcd.learningactivities/com.rcd.learningactivities.secondActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2190)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1411)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3899)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at com.rcd.learningactivities.secondActivity.onCreate(secondActivity.java:16)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5260)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    ... 11 more
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

If any additional information would be helpful, please let me know... If you are able to point me in the right direction as far as where I should be looking to resolve the issue, that would be awesome as well.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my secondActivity.java

```
package com.rcd.learningactivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class secondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getShort("tbtext"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is my secondactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse logcat debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964329/eclipse-logcat-debugging)

Comment: My guess here is that you try to call `setText()` on an `EditText` and you use an `int` for the `param` instead of a `String`. [See the docs for the different methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))

Comment: Or you just have to clean the project - R file was probably not generated correctly...

Comment: Could you show us the `secondActivity.java` line 16?

Comment: [Also see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604221/cant-start-another-activity-in-android-gives-error/17604266#17604266) I'm pretty sure that's your problem but if not then post your `onCreate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big elements of debugging is being able to sort through the junk of log files and find the information that is relevant to you.  Typically, this is any part of the log that describes any part of the app that you wrote.  In this case, that would be this line right here:

```
01-22 11:26:11.877: E/AndroidRuntime(23917):    at com.rcd.learningactivities.secondActivity.onCreate(secondActivity.java:16)
```

It looks like whatever is happening on line 16 in src/com/rcd/learningactivities/secondActivity is failing because it can't find the resource (I'm assuming that it can't find the TextView.  Look at the code and compare it to the respective XML.  Do the IDs match?  Are you calling the correct method in your Java to programatically write to the text view?  Have you built the TextView object correctly in your XML?)

There could be a large number of reasons that it's not working correctly, but the key to finding it out is on line 16 of your second activity Java file.  Good luck, and happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you!  The answer was when I let eclipse auto finish my writing, it chose getShort instead of getString!  That was the problem.