# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xff000000

Tags: java, android

I am having problems in my Drawer. I am using fragments.If I try to run the "app keeps stopping" error appears.
I calculate that the problem is bindViewHolder but I don't know how to solve it...

In my SimpleItem.java

```
package com.example.papbiensaude;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Choreographer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;


public class SimpleItem extends DrawerItem<SimpleItem.ViewHolder> {

    private int selectedItemIconTint;
    private int selectedItemTextTint;

    private int normalItemIconTint;
    private int normalItemTextTint;

    private Drawable icon;
    private String title;

    public SimpleItem(Drawable icon, String title){
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.title.setText(title);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(icon);

        holder.title.setText(isChecked ? selectedItemTextTint : normalItemTextTint);
        holder.icon.setColorFilter(isChecked ? selectedItemIconTint : normalItemIconTint);
    }

    public SimpleItem withSelectedIconTint(int selectedItemIconTint){
        this.selectedItemIconTint = selectedItemIconTint;
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleItem withSelectedTextTint(int selectedItemTextTint){
        this.selectedItemTextTint = selectedItemTextTint;
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleItem withIconTint(int normalItemIconTint){
        this.normalItemIconTint = normalItemIconTint;
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleItem withTextTint(int normalItemTextTint){
        this.normalItemTextTint = normalItemTextTint;
        return this;
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView icon;
        private TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

In my  DrawerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.papbiensaude;

import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DrawerItem> items;
    private Map<Class<? extends DrawerItem>, Integer> viewTypes;
    private SparseArray<DrawerItem> holderFactories;

    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    public DrawerAdapter( List<DrawerItem> items){
        this.items = items ;
        this.viewTypes = new HashMap<>();
        this.holderFactories = new SparseArray<>();
        processViewTypes();
    }

    private void processViewTypes() {
        int type = 0;
        for (DrawerItem item : items){
            if(!viewTypes.containsKey(item.getClass())){
                viewTypes.put(item.getClass(),type);
                holderFactories.put(type, item);
                type++;
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       ViewHolder holder = holderFactories.get(viewType).createViewHolder(parent);
       holder.drawerAdapter = this;
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        items.get(position).bindViewHolder(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return viewTypes.get(items.get(position).getClass());
    }

    public void setSelected(int position){
        DrawerItem newChecked = items.get(position);
        if (!newChecked.isSelectable()){
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++){
             DrawerItem item = items.get(i);
             if (item.isChecked()){
                 item.setChecked(false);
                 notifyItemChanged(i);
                 break;
             }
        }

        newChecked.setChecked(true);
        notifyItemChanged(position);

        if (listener != null){
            listener.onItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    public void setListener(OnItemSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener{
        void onItemSelected(int position);
    }


    static abstract class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private  DrawerAdapter drawerAdapter;

        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v){
            drawerAdapter.setSelected(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xff000000
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
        at com.example.papbiensaude.SimpleItem.bindViewHolder(SimpleItem.java:42)
        at com.example.papbiensaude.SimpleItem.bindViewHolder(SimpleItem.java:14)
        at com.example.papbiensaude.DrawerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrawerAdapter.java:52)
        at com.example.papbiensaude.DrawerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrawerAdapter.java:16)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
2021-02-04 17:12:28.114 15544-15544/com.example.papbiensaude E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I still don't understand where the error is and how to recover it!

Comment: `holder.title.setText(isChecked ? selectedItemTextTint : normalItemTextTint);` here you seem to set an int value as text. The runtime thinks you want to pass in a string resource id. If you don't, make sure to only use String or CharSequence, never an int

Comment: See also the documentation for [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189545/android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is here:

> ```
> holder.title.setText(isChecked ? selectedItemTextTint : normalItemTextTint);
> ```

The `setText(int)` method is expecting a *string resource identifier*, something like `R.string.my_string`. You're presumably (accidentally) passing it a *color int*: `0xff000000` (opaque black).

Either change `setText()` to `setTextColor()` or change the argument to be a string resource id.