# Problem resolving an android.content.res.Resources error

Tags: java, android, string, exception, resources

I understand that this error has been addressed severally and I've checked most of them like [Android: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189545/android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x), [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388586/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id) to see if I could find a solution to my problem but I couldn't and most of them are hard to understand. I can't tell if my code is an int/string so I don't know exactly what to correct, so I need help.

I got this error at runtime:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x601ee924
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5848)
        at com.tex.lightweatherforecast.Activity.HomeActivity$1.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:66)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

My codes:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String BaseUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org";
    public static String AppId = "";
    public static String lat = "9.0574";
    public static String lon = "7.4898";
    // User Timezone name, current time
    TextView time_zone, time_field;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.dubai,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        time_zone = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        time_field = findViewById(R.id.textView9);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                    assert weatherResponse != null;

                    assert response.body() != null;
                    time_zone.setText(response.body().getTimezone());
                    time_field.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getDt());




                    constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on ui thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (count < drawable.length) {

                        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                        count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
    }
}

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public static String BaseUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org";
    public static String AppId = "";
    public static String lat = "9.0574";
    public static String lon = "7.4898";
    // User Timezone name, current time, current temperature, current condition, sunrise, sunset, temperature, pressure, humidity, wind_speed, visibility, UV Index
    TextView current_temp, current_output, rise_time, set_time, temp_out, Press_out, Humid_out, Ws_out, Visi_out, UV_out;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        current_temp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        current_output = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        rise_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        set_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        temp_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        Press_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        Humid_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        Ws_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView33);
        Visi_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        UV_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView35);


                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
                Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                            assert weatherResponse != null;

                            assert response.body() != null;
                            current_temp.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
                            current_output.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                            rise_time.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getSunrise() + " AM"));
                            set_time.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getSunset() + " PM"));
                            temp_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
                            Press_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getPressure() + " hpa"));
                            Humid_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getHumidity() + " %"));
                            Ws_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getWindSpeed() + " Km/h"));
                            Visi_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getVisibility() + " m"));

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
           return rootView;
            }


    }
```

In my **String.xml**:

```
<string name="blank">%s &#x2103;</string>
```

Comment: In which line of code you got this exception?

Comment: @Zain i don't know the line, but i know it's going to be from my setText which is either this part time_zone.setText(response.body().getTimezone());
time_field.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getDt()); or this part current_temp.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
                         current_output.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                            rise_time.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getSunrise() + " AM"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x601ee924
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5848)
        at com.tex.lightweatherforecast.Activity.HomeActivity$1.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:66)
```

As shown above, the exception is raised in `HomeActivity` in `onResponse()` method line (66) where you try to set a text into a `TextView`.

So, In `HomeActivity` you've:

```
 time_field.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getDt());
```

And as per [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api), `.getDt()` returns an integer, so you can't set it directly to `TextView` unless you convert it to a String.

To solve this, replace that line of code with one of:

```
 // 1st
 time_field.setText(String.valueOf(response.body().getCurrent().getDt()));

 // 2nd
 time_field.setText("" + response.body().getCurrent().getDt());
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast value of `position` to `String`. Concatenating with another `String` is one of the ways to do it

```
setText("" + position)
```

Comment: Please add why this is a solution to the problem at hand

Comment: Isn't it the same solution as suggested by Zain anyway? At the end of their answer...