# Fatal exception causes device reboot

Tags: android

I am currently having an issue with an android app where my device will reboot randomly. I cannot reproduce it consistently. With Logcat I was able to get this error message:

```
 02-08 14:33:49.288 W/ContextImpl( 3581): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1357 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.license.type.BootReceiver.onReceive:24 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3046 
 --------- beginning of crash
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581): Process: com.license.type, PID: 3581
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.license.type.MyService: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b002a
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3207)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b002a
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:381)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at com.license.type.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:61)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3197)
 02-08 14:33:49.303 E/AndroidRuntime( 3581):     ... 8 more
 02-08 14:33:49.415 I/ActivityManager(  548): Process com.license.type (pid 3581) has died
```

Does anyone have an idea from where to start looking for a possible cause? Google also brings nothing up from searching for "com.license.type".

I have tested on both an Android 7 and 9 device, with the error occurring there as well.

If I can offer more information that might be able to assist, please ask away.

Thanks all

Comment: This is a little unclear. You're having this problem while developing your own app? And you don't know what the `com.license.type` package is? What about `MyService`? Is that one of your class names?

Comment: I have no reference to "com.license.type" or MyService in my application. And yes I get the issue intermittently while using my app on my device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189545/android-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x/30789639#30789639

The issue looks similar to this, however I have a default strings.xml file so this fix will not help me.

Comment: `String resource ID #0x7f0b002a` If you convert from hexadecimal you get *

Comment: Yeah, the root Exception is a basic, common error that you can get anywhere in any app, so that's not gonna help pin this down. To that end, AFAICT, the only thing helpful in that trace is the `com.license.type.MyService`.

Comment: Are you testing on physical devices, or on emulators? If physical, which brands and models? Are you developing with the SDK/NDK directly, or are you using some framework on top of that; e.g., React, Delphi, Flutter, etc.?

Comment: I am testing on physical devices, Rockchip RK3399. I am developing with the SDK. There is unity wrapped in my application.

Comment: I have exited my app and ran `adb shell am startservice com.license.type/.MyService` I do see the same fatal error in Logcat, but my device stays on this time.

Comment: Well, I've never worked with such a setup, so I'll refrain from making any suggestions, for fear that I'd just be wasting our time. That's a good idea and lead with the adb command, though. At least you know that that Service's Exception alone isn't the whole issue.

Comment: `0x7f0b002a` is usually refers to color id used in your app. So if you can build your app, then start fresh, clean previous caches.

Comment: I have done multiple builds and clear cache every time. Are you referring to color in the sense of the RGB? I believe that takes 6 hex characters while `0x7f0b002a` has 7. Unless you were referring to something else?


Just doesn't make sense to me that it happens randomly at different stages of the flow in the app. If it always breaks at the same spot it would be much easier to pin down the cause. Sometimes my app is stable and open for multiple hours.

Comment: We had to go into kmesg to get more info, related to a different module failing. This stack trace was a red herring unfortunately...I think